# JavaScript: Check if window.location.href has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, window.location

I have following code to show a loading panel after e.g. clicking a button and making an Ajax call:

```
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        window.LoadingPanel.Show();
    });
```

After the Ajax call following code makes sure the loading panel disappears again:

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        if (window.LoadingPanel != null) {
            window.LoadingPanel.Hide();
        }
    });
```

But in some cases I redirect to another page depending on the result of the Ajax call by setting the `window.location.href`.
In this case I want the `ajaxComplete` function NOT to hide the loading panel too early until the redirect has been succeeded.

How can I check in the `ajaxComplete` function if the window.location.href has been changed and the page is about to redirect?

Comment: if redirect means load a new full page in browser what you are asking can't be done. Each page is it's own window instance

Comment: Why not just set a flag based on the result of your AJAX call? If it's true, hide the panel, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a good way to solve this problem but thats what i can think of now.

1. create a variable call isHide = true;

2. In your jax call Onsuccess function set isHide = false if hiding is not require.

3. in your ajaxComplete see following

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e) {
    if (window.LoadingPanel != null && isHide) {
        window.LoadingPanel.Hide();
    }
});
```